# Cannot Open Database - The User Login Failed - VB.NET 2012 MVC 4

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

**Edit:** *The SQL connection has gotten updated.*

**The Controller:**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient   

Function SQLSelect() As ActionResult

    Dim theconnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=MSSQLSERVER;server=(localdb)\Projects;Database=test_drive_database;User Id=xxxx_user-PC\xxxx_user;password=;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=True;")
    theconnection.Open()

    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT * FROM ColorTable"
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString)
    command.BeginExecuteNonQuery()

    command.CommandTimeout = 15
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    'Printing Out the SQL Result

    Return ViewData("command")

End Function
```

**The Error Messages:**

```
Cannot open database "test_drive_database" requested by the login. The login failed.

Login failed for user 'xxxx_user-PC\xxxx_user'.
```

How to find out why exactly the login failed?

**Notice:** *No password is used.*

**Addendum:**

```
        Dim theconnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=MSSQLSERVER;server=(localdb)\Projects;Database=ColorTable_database.sdf;Integrated Security=sspi;")
    theconnection.Open()
```

This is also a variation I have tried, though I am getting the same error message.

Comment: You have already posted a question like this and in that question you spoke of Sql Compact not SqlExpress. Could you clarify this point?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483893/how-to-specifically-check-if-the-sql-database-has-gotten-opened-vb-net-2012-m

Comment: I have followed this guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms143744%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx "When you run SQL Server Express, by default, the named instance option is selected with SQLExpress as the instance name." - Whereas using MSSQLSERVER is possible as well.

Comment: I have updated the question with a new variation I have tried. Nevertheless, I am getting the same error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The Login Fails - TimeOut Reportings in the Stack Trace - VB.NET 4.5 MVC 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492957/the-login-fails-timeout-reportings-in-the-stack-trace-vb-net-4-5-mvc-4)

Answer (score 2):

Reference [Connection strings for SQL Server](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005#sqlconnection) 
Change your connection string in the following way:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

If you want to login with default login(Window Login) then use the following one for the Trusted Connection:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

So your connection object should be as:

```
Dim theconnection As New SqlConnection("server=(localdb)\Projects; _
                          Database=test_drive_database;Trusted_Connection=True;")
```

If this does not solve the problem then it may be permission problem of the user.
Check the reference links:

[SQL Server Asp.Net - "Login failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804543/sql-server-asp-net-login-failed)
[Login failed for SQL Server user through asp.net page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502763/login-failed-for-sql-server-user-through-asp-net-page)
[SQL Server: Login failed for user](http://forums.asp.net/t/1053234.aspx/1)
[Login failed for user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab4e6cky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try to add "Trusted_Connection = true;" on the connection string.